# return unique combinations of items R?

Tags: r, vector, unique, purrr

Given multiple vectors I'd like to return the unique combinations of columns across the vectors. Here is an example that works but isn't as fast as computationally fast as I'd like:

```r
library(dplyr)

c_sort_collapse <- function(...){
  c(...) %>% 
    sort() %>% 
    paste(collapse = ".")
}

unique_set <- function(...){
  list(...) %>% 
    purrr::pmap_chr(c_sort_collapse) %>% 
    unique()
}

unique_set(c("a", "b", "a"), c("a", "a", "b"))
#> [1] "a.a" "a.b"
```

Is there a way to do this that is faster / better vectorized, i.e. doesn't depend on looping through each item (like happens in the `purrr::pmap_chr()` step)?

Comment: Shouldn't you have also b.a? In other words is this combination or permutations?

Comment: I care about just combinations, so I'm saying "b.a" is not unique because already have "a.b"

Comment: I cross-posted this question on Twitter and got a number of responses with different approaches there: https://twitter.com/brshallo/status/1555554718495100928?s=20&t=yW4HnvaPfjpGjkEnqVlxEg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution only works when there is two vectors to combine, but is pretty fast. I took the liberty of giving other methods the advantage of `stringi::stri_sort()` which already is an order of magnitude faster.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)

set.seed(123)
x <- sample(letters, 1000, replace = TRUE)

set.seed(12)
y <- sample(letters, 1000, replace = TRUE)

c_sort_collapse <- function(...){
  c(...) |> 
    stri_sort() |> 
    paste(collapse = ".")
}

unique_set <- function(...){
  list(...) |> 
    purrr::pmap_chr(c_sort_collapse) |> 
    unique()
}

unique_set_matrix <- function(...){
  matrix(c(...), nrow = length(list(...)), byrow = TRUE) |>
    apply(2, stri_sort) |>
    asplit(2) |>
    unique() |>
    sapply(paste, collapse = ".")
}

pminmax <- function(x, y) {
  paste(pmin.int(x, y), pmax.int(x, y), sep = ".") |> unique()
}

all.equal(sort(unique_set(x, y)), sort(pminmax(x, y)))
#> [1] TRUE

bench::mark(
  tidy = unique_set(x, y),
  matrix = unique_set_matrix(x, y),
  Map = Map(\(x,y) paste0(stri_sort(c(x,y)) , collapse = ".") , x , y) |>
    unique() |> unlist(FALSE, FALSE),
  pminmax = pminmax(x, y),
  iterations = 20, check = FALSE
)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 tidy         6.13ms   6.24ms      160.    45.4KB     17.8
#> 2 matrix       5.18ms   5.55ms      168.   229.8KB     29.7
#> 3 Map           5.7ms   6.83ms      151.    33.4KB     16.7
#> 4 pminmax     484.6µs 487.85µs     2035.    49.6KB      0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Nice! That's a major speed-up! Very clever! Going to hold-off on marking it "best answer" for now to see if something comes-in with major speed-up and that handles arbitrary number of inputs but for my current use-case, this is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

We can use **`Base R`** `Map` function

```
library(stringi)

Map(\(x,y) paste0(stri_sort(c(x,y)) , collapse = ".") , x , y) |>
   unique() |> unlist()
```

- output

```
[1] "a.a" "a.b"
```

- data

```
x <- c("a", "b", "a")
y <- c("a", "a", "b")
```

***Edited***

I think using `stri_sort` from `stringi` library make good results in my `microbenchmark` tests , try it.

```
library(stringi)

x <- c("a", "b", "a")
y <- c("a", "a", "b")

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    tidy = unique_set(x, y),
    base = Map(\(x,y) paste0(stri_sort(c(x,y)) , collapse = ".") , x , y) |>
        unique() |> unlist(),
    times = 1000
)

#<============ Results ===============>#

Unit: microseconds
 expr    min      lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
 tidy 93.284 96.8405 102.09465 100.1805 103.4035  244.337  1000
 base 37.271 39.2190  44.15599  41.6520  43.5285 1860.692  1000
```

Comment: I don't think base R's Map() has any real speed advantages does it? A quick speed test suggests it's roughly the same; https://gist.github.com/brshallo/a90bcc258f436b428ba4c23cd56cae96

Comment: Having updated using  `stri_sort` from `stringi` package.

Comment: Thanks! `stri_sort()` definitely speeds things up. If you apply that to either the tidy or your solution though get similar speed improvements.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution that works only for two vectors. It's based on `fifelse` from data.table package. I also compare with `pminmax` from @teunbrand solution:

```
library(data.table)

pminmax <- function(x, y) {
  paste(pmin.int(x, y), pmax.int(x, y), sep = ".") |> unique()
}

dtfifelse = function(x, y) {
  {idx=x<y; paste0(fifelse(idx, x, y), ".", fifelse(idx, y, x)) |> unique()}
}

compare = function(n) {
  set.seed(0123)
  # random sample of strings with up to 10 characters
  x = stringi::stri_rand_strings(n, sample(10, n, TRUE))   
  y = stringi::stri_rand_strings(n, sample(10, n, TRUE))   
  #
  bench::mark(
    pminmax = pminmax(x, y),
    dt_fifelse = dtfifelse(x, y),
    iterations = 5, 
    check = TRUE
  )[1:9]
}

compare(1e3)
# A tibble: 2 x 9
  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
1 pminmax      1.99ms   2.03ms      468.    43.4KB        0     5     0    10.68ms
2 dt_fifelse   1.61ms   1.72ms      546.    47.4KB        0     5     0     9.16ms

compare(1e4)
# A tibble: 2 x 9
  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
1 pminmax     10.42ms  11.03ms      89.6     480KB        0     5     0     55.8ms
2 dt_fifelse   8.16ms   8.34ms     120.      519KB        0     5     0     41.7ms

compare(1e5)
# A tibble: 2 x 9
  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
1 pminmax       124ms    127ms      7.74    4.43MB     1.93     4     1      517ms
2 dt_fifelse    100ms    105ms      9.51    4.81MB     0        5     0      526ms

compare(1e6)
# A tibble: 2 x 9
  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
1 pminmax       1.31s    1.34s     0.748    42.3MB     1.12     2     3      2.67s
2 dt_fifelse    1.07s    1.07s     0.932    46.1MB     1.40     2     3      2.15s
```